# Pushing C# queue data to Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have a Asp.net web page that connects to a WCF service and retrieves data via a WCF Web Socket connection as below.
        **Default.aspx.cs**

```
    public static List<String> lstStud = new List<String>();

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<String> GetData()
    {
        queueItems.Dequeue(value);
        lstStud.Add(value);
        return lstStud;
    }

    public static Queue<string> queueItems = new Queue<string>();

    private class CallbackHandler : Service1.IRestServiceImplCallback
    {
        public async Task SendDataAsync(string value)
        {
            //do something here
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", value);
        }
        public async void SendData(string value)
        {
            if (queueItems != null)
            {
                if (value != "No Data")
                {
                    queueItems.Enqueue(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I successfully receive data in the async SendData callback method. I'm not able to display this data on the UI as data comes in. My google searches have pointed me in the direction of Angular. would Angular be a favorable approach to solve this problem?

```
**Default.aspx**
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"runat="server">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="dataCtrl" ng-app="app">

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <tr ng-repeat="data in data">
                <td>{{data}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
</asp:Content>

**data.js:**
app.value('pageMethods', PageMethods);

app.factory('mydata', function (pageMethods, $rootScope) {
    var result = [];
    pageMethods.GetData(function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            result.push({ id: item.Id});
        });
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });
    return result;
})

**dataCtrl.js**
app.controller('dataCtrl', function ($scope, data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Comment: Well, if your problem is UI related. Show your AngularJS code.

Comment: Added the Default.aspx and .js code

Comment: I'm not sure how to update the UI when there is a new item in the queueItems

Comment: Where is `data` defined in your AngularJS application? Please add your dataCtrl.

Comment: my bad. just added the dataCtrl.js

Comment: Please also add `pageMethods` include your `GetData()` function ..

Comment: The GetData() function is included in the code

Comment: How is a JavaScript running in your Frontend able to directly call a C# function?

Comment: As i said before I've added AngularJS to the UI to enable this functionality